# Widget compilado en un solo archivo e incrustable

Tags: javascript, html, modal, widget

Estoy haciendo una maqueta de un widget para que sea incrustado en cualquier aplicación web de cualquier cliente, para ello ese widget debe de entregarse en un solo archivo para sea fácil de implementar e incrustar en cualquier lugar.
Si lo hago con angular v-14 no tengo la opción de comprimirlo en un solo archivo con ng build --single bundle, además será algo estático y no es necesario hacerlo con ningún framework.
Si hago un proyecto con html5, css, javascript y Bootstrap como podré luego compilarlo en un solo archivo?
También, ese widget se abrirá en forma de modal al hacer click en la página del cliente, donde se pondrá la lógica para que se haga en forma de modal, en la web del cliente o en mi widget?

Comment: Creo que lo que quieres hacer es una pequeña app que este desplegada en un dominio y por medio de Iframe incrustarlo en un modal, creo que seria la solución, ya la tecnología que uses seria lo de menos

Comment: Puedes hacer un "Web Component" y colocar todo dentro de un solo archivo js. También puedes hacerlo con typescript y al compilarlo le puedes decir que todo lo guarde en un solo archivo.